# How to transform a desktop version of Ubuntu ISO into a server one?

Tags: package-management, iso

As I understand, desktop and server distributions of Ubuntu are very similar, except that some packages are included in one but not another.

I need to install Ubuntu Server from PXE. Since [there is no way to install official Ubuntu Server from PXE](https://askubuntu.com/q/476508/229568), but is easy to do with the desktop variant, what do I need to do to change the list of packages (and only that) on an Ubuntu Desktop ISO in order to be able to have an Ubuntu Server variant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server install runs this:

Used by Server install to choose what you want

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

If you uninstall the meta-package, then you may just have the server. Not sure if it un-installs too much??

The key meta packages of Ubuntu are :
ubuntu-base (the whole base system which everybody should install)

ubuntu-desktop (the whole gnome environment)

kubuntu-desktop (the whole kde environment)

xubuntu-desktop (the whole xfce4 environment)

lubuntu-desktop (the whole LXDE desktop environment)

edubuntu-desktop (the whole kids/schools oriented gnome environment)

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop
```

[Is it possible to install Ubuntu through network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339427/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-through-network)

Answer (score 1):

Although I have never done it, there is a popular program called Ubuntu Creator that allows you to take Ubuntu .iso disk images and modify them. Modify the default settings after you boot, include drivers for certain hardware, or for changing what packages are included (which is what you need to do). However, I don't know how well it will work for you, as it tis not endorsed by Canonical.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove most of the desktop stuff with the metapackage:

apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop

That will strip you back but leave python and all the rest that's needed.